# words change animation working in Chrome but not in Safari

Tags: html, css

I've just been trying to set up a simple text animation on my website. Basically every few seconds, I'd like the words to change (e.g. from 'graphic design' to 'illustration' and so on). The animation works fine in Chrome but not in Safari, where it doesn't play. I've tried adding the -webkit prefix, but maybe the problem is the :before element?
You can check the website at matteobisato.design and below is a snippet of the code

- about /
- works /
- contact /
- instagram /

matteo bisato

.bigwords {font-size: 4em; font-family: Atlas Grotesk Web; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: 110%;
            margin-left: 40px; padding-top: 72px; margin-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; z-index: -1; background-color: transparent; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            opacity: 0.5; mix-blend-mode: difference}

```
        .bigwords:before {content: normal; animation-name: animate; animation-duration: 20s; 
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;}

        @keyframes animate { 
            from {content: 'editorial design.'} 20% {content: 'graphic design.'} 30% {content:'motion graphics.'}
            40% {content: 'visual culture.'} 50% {content: 'moving image.'} 60% {content: 'sound.'} 70% {content: 'branding.'}
            80% {content: 'logo design.'} 90% {content: 'photo editing.'} to {content: 'illustration.'}
        }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You must specify [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) for all target browsers.

```
.bigwords:before {
    content: normal; 
    animation-name: animate; 
    -webkit-animation-name: animate;
    -moz-animation-name: animate;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately even this way it doesn't work on Safari (I am using Safari 13.0.5 by the way)